# Laravel: header view cannot be yielded by layout file when accessing body view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My goal is to have my `layout.blade.php` to automatically `@yield` the `header.blade.php` when the body view is accessed through the route.

### UPDATE

I also want to avoid defining the header view in the body view as it may grow with multiple different contents in different view files. In future when I need to change to different header view, I only need to change it at the layout file, e.g. `@yield("header2")`.

---

The following are the files:

Stored in `resources/views/layouts/layout.blade.php`

```
<body>
    @yield('header')
    @yield('body')
</body>
```

Stored in `resources/views/headers/header.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('header')
<h1>
    My Header
</h1>
@endsection
```

Stored in `resources/views/body.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('body')
<div class="content">
   This is body!
</div>
@endsection
```

Stored in `routes/web.php`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/body', function () {
    return view('body');
});
```

But when accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/body, my header is not appearing, why? According to **Bing AI Chatbot**, she is able to render the header by following the above structure, I wonder why I can't. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the answers provided here are almost correct, just that:

1. Some do not explain why the `@section('header')` has to be put in the body view in order for it to be yielded by the layout.
2. Some do not meet my updated goal, that is to avoid repeating the `@section('header')` definition in the body view as it grows to multiple files with different contents.

After some further studies and experiments, I think I've managed to figure out why the `@section('header')` cannot be yielded and displayed in the layout file:

### The Problem

[image]

Based on my understanding, whether the view can be yielded by the layout or not depends on the following factors:

1. The view file that the `view()` helper is triggered in the router.
2. Whether the view triggered `@extends` the layout.
3. Whether the section to be yielded in the layout exists in the view file triggered by the router.

According to my experiment, even if I change the sequence of the `@yield` in the layout file, the header will not overwrite the body as mentioned by **@Archana U B**:

```
<body>
    <!-- Body will still be displayed --> 
    @yield('body') 
    <!-- Header has been ignored --> 
    @yield('header')
</body>
```

### Solution 1

As some have mentioned, unless all the required sections are in the same view file, otherwise none can be yielded in the extended layout file:
[image]

But the disadvantage of this solution, as required by the updated goal in this question, is that changing to `@yield('header2')` in the layout file may **require to change all the relevant view files with different contents**.

### Solution 2

To avoid repeating the header section definition in each of the body views, it looks like we can only use `@include('headers.header')` in `layout.blade.php`:
[image]

This solution is good when you have **hundreds of body views** that extend the layout file with different contents without repeating the header and footer definitions (although the `@include()` can be used within the `@section()`). This decouples the body views from header, footer, and sidebar, letting the developers to focus only on the layout file. But sadly, this could make the **1-Layout-to-Many-Sections** architecture serves little purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not including your header in your body blade file:

```
// Stored in resources/views/body.blade.php

@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('header')
    @include('headers.header')
@endsection

@section('body')
    <div class="content">
        This is body!
    </div>
@endsection
```

Also, you should remove @extends('layouts.layout') from header file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

In your **body.blade.php** file:

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('header')
    @include('headers.header')
@endsection

@section('body')
<div class="content">
   This is body!
</div>
@endsection
```

In your **header.blade.php** file:

```
@section('header')
<h1>
    My Header
</h1>
@endsection
```

Comment: But with this architecture, I may need to change all my body view files when I need to use a different header file. I'm expecting to change `@yield('header2')` at the layout file without changing all the body views.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your header is not appearing is because you are extending the layout.blade.php file in both the header.blade.php and body.blade.php views. This causes the layout.blade.php file to be included twice in the final rendered output, resulting in the header being overwritten or not appearing at all.

To fix this issue, you should remove the @extends('layouts.layout') directive from the header.blade.php view since it is unnecessary. The header.blade.php view should only contain the content for the header itself.

Try This:

layout.blade.php:

```
<body>
    @yield('header')
    @yield('body')
</body>
```

header.blade.php:

```
<h1>
    My Header
</h1>
```

body.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('body')
 <div class="content">
   This is body!
 </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of structure you have created for your blade is wrong.

layouts/layout.blade.php file

```
<body>
 @include('header')

 @yield('body')
</body>
```

headers/header.blade.php file

```
<h1>@yield('header1')</h1>
```

body.blade.php file

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('header1')
    This is Header1
@endsection

@section('body')
     This is Body
@endsection
```